# Matlab-Making video from images

Tags: matlab, video

Im trying to make a video from a file with 95 images in matlab.When i run the program,i get this error:

```
Error using VideoWriter/writeVideo (line 383)
Frame must be 481 by 272

Error in savenew (line 14)
 writeVideo(writerObj,im2frame(Frame)
```

Although when the number of images that i use for making the video is under 11 i     have no problem and the program is constructing the video that i want.Do you know how i can fix the problem?

Thanks in advance

Here is my update code:

```
    ImagesFolder=uigetdir;
jpegFiles = dir(strcat(ImagesFolder,'\*.jpg'));

S = [jpegFiles(:).datenum]; 
[S,S] = sort(S);
jpegFilesS = jpegFiles(S);
VideoFile=strcat(ImagesFolder,'\MyVideo');
writerObj = VideoWriter(VideoFile);
fps= 10; 
writerObj.FrameRate = fps;

open(writerObj);
for t= 1:length(jpegFilesS)
     Frame=imread(strcat(ImagesFolder,'\',jpegFilesS(t).name));
     B = imresize(Frame, 1.0);
     C=im2double(B);

     writeVideo(writerObj,im2frame(C));

end
close(writerObj);
implay('C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2013a\bin\sfalmata neo\MyVideo.avi');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All frames of a video must have the same size. Resize your frames using 'imresize'. In case of different data types also apply 'im2double'

Comment: Thank you for your answer but i have the same problem again

Comment: You are resizing with a factor of 1,that does nothing. Set the pixel dimensions using imresize

Comment: i have already try it with different factors such as 0.5 or 1.5 but i always get the same error.Maybe some frames havent got the right dimensions but i checked this and found no problem.The images in the folder are grayscale,is this a problem?

Comment: You have to set the dimensions, restyling with a factor does not make all frames the same size. Use `imresize(Frame, [w, h]) ` where w and h sets the resolution of your video.